# Display a form field only when a specific value is selected

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

How to make it possible form.gender field only display when a 'Lost Person' is selected from form.category through dropdownlist which is getting from a category table......................

index.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="personForm" data-cities-url="{% url 
'ajax_load_areas_products' %}" novalidate  >
          {% csrf_token %}
         
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            {{ form.category | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              {{form.product|as_crispy_field}}
            </div>
         </div>
         
         <div class="row">

          <div  class="col-md-6" >
            {{ form.title | as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form.gender | as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form.description | as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form.photo | as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">

          </div>
         </div>
          <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4" type="submit">Submit Post</button>
          
        </form>
```

views.py

```
def PostCreate(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid():  
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard') 
    else: 
        form = PostForm() 
    return render(request, 'chained/post_form.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: you can try using javascript change event on your category list, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Answer (score 0):

Set attr `display:none` to your forms. You need to write a javascript function and trigger it when elements on your dropdown list get clicked. There are two ways to achieve this, either your drop down elements can be buttons which trigger the js code directly or they can be other elements and js function can be triggered by their class or id. Let's say you decided to go with the button, your button should look like:

```
<button onclick="display_form(1)"></b>
```

`display_form` function gets triggered when you click this one and you also pass the value "1" to it which tells it what to do. The function:

```
function display_form(number){
      if(number == 1){
      "here you set the required form's display attr to block and hide all the others"
}
      else if(number == 2)...
```

If you don't get it at all just spend couple of hours studying javascript, you'll grasp it quickly. Good luck!